# Use SUBSTRING_INDEX syntax on MySQL database version 5.5.62

Tags: mysql, string, substring

The version of MySQL database is 5.5.62

This is my table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `dotablenew`;
+-----+-------------+
| sID | sStringNew  |
+-----+-------------+
|   1 | D1080 ARE A |
|   2 | D5258 SEG   |
|   3 | D0749 COR   |
|   4 | D4278 VAI   |
|   5 | D2664 PON   |
+-----+-------------+
5 rows in set
```

I need this return

```
+-------+------+
| sOne  | sTwo |
+-------+------+
| D1080 | ARE  |
| D5258 | SEG  |
| D0749 | COR  |
| D4278 | VAI  |
| D2664 | PON  |
+-------+------+
```

And I have tried this solution

```
mysql> SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStringNew, ' ', 1) AS sOne,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStringNew, ' ', - 1) AS sTwo
FROM
    `dotablenew`;
+-------+------+
| sOne  | sTwo |
+-------+------+
| D1080 | A    |
| D5258 | SEG  |
| D0749 | COR  |
| D4278 | VAI  |
| D2664 | PON  |
+-------+------+
5 rows in set
```

Without success because the first row is wrong

```
+-------+------+
| sOne  | sTwo |
+-------+------+
| D1080 | A    |
+-------+------+
```

I really don't know how many spaces can be in the string **sStringNew** but I always need to extract the first two elements of the string **sStringNew** separated by space...

How to do resolve this?

Please, any suggestion

My table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dotablenew`;
CREATE TABLE `dotablenew` (
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sStringNew` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of dotablenew
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `dotablenew` VALUES ('1', 'D1080 ARE A');
INSERT INTO `dotablenew` VALUES ('2', 'D5258 SEG');
INSERT INTO `dotablenew` VALUES ('3', 'D0749 COR');
INSERT INTO `dotablenew` VALUES ('4', 'D4278 VAI');
INSERT INTO `dotablenew` VALUES ('5', 'D2664 PON');
```

Comment: Haven't seen someone explaining the question this much nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStringNew, ' ', 1) AS sOne,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStringNew, ' ', 2)), ' ', 1)) AS sTwo
FROM
    `dotablenew`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sStringNew, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStringNew, ' ', 1) AS sOne,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sStringNew, ' ',  2), ' ', -1) AS sTwo
FROM
    `dotablenew`
```

Comment: Better answer than mine.